# toBinaryString has leading 1's

Tags: java, binary

I'm using toBinaryString in a simple calculator to convert an integer into its binary equivalent, and whenever doing any mathematical operation besides addition I get leading 1's, and 0's that shouldn't be there.

For example, I subtract five from 10 which should give 5 or 101 in binary, but instead I get

> Output: 11111111111111111111111111110001

Is this an issue with toBinaryString that I don't know about, or am I doing something wrong?

***Main Code:***

```
    if (input == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("- ADDITION -");
        toDo = operator.getInputs(input); // Gets how many values to input.
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(toDo);
        operator.addToList(list, toDo); // Adds values input to list.
        operator.addBinary(list); // Add values in 'list' together.
    }

    if (input == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("- Subtraction -");
        toDo = operator.getInputs(input); // Gets how many values to input.
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(toDo);
        operator.addToList(list, toDo); // Adds values input to list.
        operator.subBinary(list); // Subtract values in 'list' for eachother.
    }

    if (input == 3)
    {
        System.out.println("- Multiplication -");
        toDo = operator.getInputs(input); // Gets how many values to input.
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(toDo);
        operator.addToList(list, toDo); // Adds values input to list.
        operator.multBinary(list); // Multiplies values in 'list' together.
    }
```

***Methods:***

```
class binaryOperations
{
private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int getInputs(int b)
{
    int input;
    System.out.println("How many integers do you wish to input: ");
    return input = scan.nextInt();
}

int printBinary(int b) // Number to convert
{
    String foo = Integer.toBinaryString(b); // Convert input to binary
    return (Integer.parseInt(foo));
}

ArrayList<Integer> addToList(ArrayList<Integer> list, int toDo)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < toDo; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            System.out.println("Please enter the first integer:");
        else
            System.out.println("Please enter the next integer: ");

        int input = scan.nextInt();
        list.add(input);
    }
    return list;
}


// Addition //
void addBinary(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
    int temp = 0, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= list.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        temp = list.get(i);
        sum += temp;
    }

    String foo = Integer.toBinaryString(sum); // convert the sum to a string

    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in binary is " + foo);
}

// Subtraction //
void subBinary(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
    int temp = 0, difference = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= list.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        temp = list.get(i);
        difference -= temp;
    }

    String foo = Integer.toBinaryString(difference); // convert the difference to a string

    System.out.println("The difference of the numbers in binary is " + foo);
}

// Multiplication //
void multBinary(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
    int temp = 0, products = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= list.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        temp = list.get(i);
        products *= temp;
    }

    String foo = Integer.toBinaryString(products);

    System.out.println("The products of the numbers in binary is " + foo);
}
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't they be there? You have such convoluted code just to show one issue. Please provide a [MCVE] and explain what you think is wrong with it.

Comment: @Pillar well if the binary value of 1 is 00000001 why is it that when doing subtraction I get

`The difference of the numbers in binary is 11111111111111111111111111111111` and when doing addition I get the correct single 1?

Comment: The problem is in `subBinary` logic, not the `toBinaryString` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `subBinary` is not working well. What it does is:

```
0 - firstElementofList - secondElementofList ...
```

so in your case if your list contains {10,5} you will get -15 which is exactly represented by following binary value:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110001
```

What you need to do is to change it probably to subtract the rest from the first one:

```
void subBinary(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
    int temp = 0, difference = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= list.size() - 1; i++)
    {
       temp = list.get(i);
       difference -= temp;
    }

    String foo = Integer.toBinaryString(difference); // convert the difference to a string

    System.out.println("The difference of the numbers in binary is " + foo);
}
```

Now if you supply `{5,10}` you will get `-5`

Comment: I actually thought this was the case, so I inverted my input and did 5 and then 10 which should be {5, 10} and I still got the same output.

Comment: It will always be the same output for the same set of input. what @Pooya is talking about is your logic for the function, you should start with `difference = list.get(0)` then start subtracting all the other values in the list from `difference`. What you are currently doing is subtract all the value you have in the list from `0`

Comment: @MarwanAlani I see now after the edits. Thanks for the help. I don't know why I didn't notice that.